# upload and preview as repeated background image

Tags: background-image, photoshop, background-repeat

I am searching for a tool on web but didnt got any success their at all. I want to have something like upload and preview the image as background as repeated one or any other alternative...

I have this sample:

[image]

How can I preview and cut the image as a **perfect background image** as repeated one. Is it possible in Photoshop or in some similiar products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick i have recovered is crop a part of the image in a big canvas of Photoshop and then making the deuplicate copies of the layers...

If the image seems like irregular it means the cropped image is wrong so you have to change with a other or larger part of the image...

If it is regular and doesn't cut at the side onto the edge, it means image is perfect making background repeated...

Thanks...